# Extracting Data from JSON Array in Google Looker Studio

Tags: json, looker-studio

I am using a connector to use JSON formatted data in Looker Studio.

Among those data are arrays ("nocs" and "sports" as seen below). Looker Studio doesn't seem to be able to parse this information because of formatting.

```
[
  {
    "fname": "First name",
    "lname": "Last name",
    "nocs": [
      "Country name"
    ],
    "sports": [
      "Athletics"
    ],
    "group": "entourage",
    "total_points": 10730,
    "privacy": 0,
    "added_points": 400
  }
]
```

I have tried the following to extract the data from these two arrays respectively, but it is not working.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(nocs,r'(\w+(\s+|))+')
```

Any advice on how to parse these arrays into strings easily ?

Thank you very much in advance !